# i want to understand why my audio is keep playing and overlapping even when it doesnt meet if statement condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, overlapping

i wanted to play audio when i click btn
if the number of dice is 1 bombaudio should play
and if the number of dice is other than 1 diceAudio should play.

i reset the currentTime of the audio when i click the button
but somehow when i click rapidly the audio is just keep playing and overlapping dont care about the if condition i made.

i searched about it and now i can fix the problem writing audio.pause()
but i want to know why the audios are keep playing even when i click the button it generate new number and it meets new condition, they seems like they dont affected by the condition.

heres my code pen link

```
    'use strict';
     const diceAudio = new Audio('(Free) Dice Roll Sound Effect 1.mp3');
     const bombAudio = new Audio('bomb.wav');
     const rollBtn = document.querySelector('.roll-dice');

     rollBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
       let number = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        diceAudio.currentTime = 0;
        bombAudio.currentTime = 0;
      if (number == 1) {
        bombAudio.play();
      } else {
        diceAudio.play();
      }
      console.log(number);
    });
```

https://codepen.io/kido-x/pen/MWzNGyV

i expected my audio to be stop cuz when i click i reset the audio by using currentTime = 0;
and then there is a if statement.